Is the set of all non-computable numbers closed under addition?
My instinct tells me no. I would like to imagine, since most real numbers are uncomputable, there exist two real uncomputable numbers $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha+\beta=1$ but I certainly don't know how to show it.

The computable numbers are a field, therefore an subgroup of $(\Bbb R,+)$. The complement of a subgroup is never non-empty and addition-closed.

@SassatelliGiulio: Is it or isn't it addition-closed? Your sentence can mean either.

@pts Whichever is true is mine

@SassatelliGiulio: pts's question was legitimate! I would have said: "The complement of a subgroup can never be both non-empty and addition-closed."

The set of non-computable numbers is not closed under addition. Take some non-computable number $a$. Then $1-a$ and $1+a$ are also non-computable, but their sum is 2, a computable number.

Ahh, so simple. Thank you. I was led to this question because I was wondering whether the set of non computable numbers could function as a field, or a n-dimensional vector space. But I guess not

The dumber answer is just a - a.
